# QML: MouseArea in GridLayout delegate is ignored when the GridLayout itself contains a MouseArea

Tags: qml

I am trying to build a Component that lets me click a pane to add a new sub-pane to it. The sub-panes are laid out in a grid. The sub-panes themselves can be clicked to add their own sub-panes. I have figured out how to implement the dynamic creation of nested grid delegates, however I am having a problem with the mouse areas.

Here is a minimal example that demonstrates the problem: It is a `GridLayout` that is filled with a `MouseArea`. The `GridLayout` contains 8 `Panes`, each filled with their own `MouseAreas`. However, the `MouseArea` of the `GridLayout` seems to cover up the `MouseArea` of the child `Panes`. In the below example, the `rootPane` should be lighter when hovered, and then go darker again if the mouse is instead over a `delegatePane`. Likewise, the `delgatePane` should go lighter when it is hovered. Instead, the `delegatePane` `MouseArea` is completely ignored.

The z value of the child delegatePane should be higher in the visual stacking order, so this should get the mouse event.

How do I fix this?

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    component GridPane : Pane {
        id: rootPane
        Material.background: Material.Green
        anchors.fill: parent
        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 4
            rowSpacing: 20
            columnSpacing: 20
            Repeater {
                model: 8
                Pane {
                    id: delegatePane
                    Material.background: Material.Blue
                    Layout.fillWidth: true
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    MouseArea {
                        id: delegateMouseArea
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.margins: -10
                        hoverEnabled: true
                        onEntered: {
                            delegatePane.background.color = Qt.lighter(Material.background, 1.1)
                        }
                        onExited: {
                            delegatePane.background.color = Qt.darker(Material.background, 1.1)
                        }
                        onClicked: print("clicked delegatePane")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: rootMouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: -10
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                rootPane.background.color = Qt.lighter(Material.background, 1.1)
            }
            onExited: {
                rootPane.background.color = Qt.darker(Material.background, 1.1)
            }
            onClicked: print("clicked grid")
            
        }
    }

    GridPane {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

**edit**

I have tried adding this to the rootMouseArea:

```
preventStealing: true
propagateComposedEvents: true
```

Then adding this function to the delegatePane:

```
function containsMouse(x, y) {
    let x1 = delegatePane.x
    let x2 = delegatePane.x + delegatePane.width
    let y1 = delegatePane.y
    let y2 = delegatePane.y + delegatePane.height
    return (x > x1 && x < x2) && (y > y1 && y < y2)
}
```

Then adding this function to the rootPane:

```
function anyDelegatePaneContainsMouse() {
    for (let i = 0; i < delegatePaneRepeater.count; i++) {
        let delegatePane = delegatePaneRepeater.itemAt(i)
        if (delegatePane.containsMouse(rootMouseArea.mouseX, rootMouseArea.mouseY)) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And then changing the rootMouseArea onClicked to:

```
onClicked: (mouse)=> {
    if (anyDelegatePaneContainsMouse()) {
        mouse.accepted = false
    }
    else {
        print("clicked grid")
    }
}
```

However, the margins of this seem to be wrong, and I can only make this strategy work with clicks, not hovered events.

I'm hoping a simpler solution exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. I can use a negative z value. If I want deep nesting, I need to use a value equal to the negative of the max allowed depth.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true


    Block {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
    }

    component Block : Pane {
        id: block

        Material.background: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1)
        Material.elevation: 10
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        property ObjectModel model: ObjectModel{} 
        property int level: 1
        property alias maz: ma.z

        Text {
            text: `Block{level:${block.level}, len:${block.model.count}, z:${block.maz}}`
            y: parent.y - 30
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        }
        GridLayout {
            id: grid
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 4
            rowSpacing: 20
            columnSpacing: 20
            Repeater {
                model: block.model
            }
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: ma
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: -10
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton
            hoverEnabled: true
            onEntered: {
                background.color = Qt.lighter(Material.background, 1.1)
            }
            onExited: {
                background.color = Qt.darker(Material.background, 1.1)
            }
            onClicked: {
                if (block.maz>=0) {
                    console.error("Only 10 levels allowed")
                    return
                }
                let params = {
                    "level": block.level + 1,
                    "maz": block.maz + 1,
                }
                let childBlock = blockCreator.createObject(block, params)
                block.model.append(childBlock)
            }
            z: -10
        }
    }

    //A hack to dynamically create inlined components
    Component {
        id: blockCreator
        Block{}
    }

}
```